# \t not working while I try to print the Fibonnaci sequence with spaces in the middle

Tags: python, python-3.x

The first print command does work however the second one when run gives the message "unexpected character after line continuation character".

```
def fib_seq():
    n=int(input("How many terms?:"))
    n1 = 0
    n2 = 1
    if n <= 0:
        print("Incorrect input")
    elif n == 1:
        print(0)
    elif n == 2:
        print(1)
    for i in range(2,n):
            sum = n1 + n2
            n1 = n2
            n2 = sum
    print("Fibonacci\tSummation")
    print(n+\t+n2)
```

Comment: `\t` only means TAB inside a string.

Comment: `print(n, "\t", n2, sep="")` - also a missing else: with bad indentation and more problems in your code. You should learn debugging it - read [how-to-debug-small-programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Then you'll get another error, because `n1` and `n2` are numbers, and you can't concatenate numbers with strings. Use a string formatting method: `%`, `.format()`, or f-string.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use \t outside a string in python, nor \n ( newline ), etc.
In addition, you should use f-strings to print your results in a more pythonic way:

```
print(f'{n}\t{n2}')
```

Comment: note that `f-strings` are only supported on `Python3.6+` versions (not that most people already have that)